# Issue Related to Date Range in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have written following Query in SQL Server :

```
SELECT * 
FROM AttendanceMaster 
WHERE Date between '8/12/2012' AND '8/20/2012'
```

butt Query result returns  '8/13/2012' AND '8/19/2012'

but it doesn't returns result for date 12/8/2012  and for date 8/20/2012

so what is the solution to get the data for above two date ?

Comment: Are these date columns or datetime columnns, and did you mean 8/12/2012 instead of 12/8/2012 in the text? Also, better to use the long form for query dates: 2012-08-12 and 2012-08-20

Answer (score 1):

Try with following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM AttendanceMaster 
WHERE CAST(Date AS DATETIME) 
                   BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY , -1 ,CAST('2012-08-12' AS DATETIME)) AND 
                           DATEADD( DAY , 1 ,CAST('2012-08-20' AS DATETIME));
```

Answer (score 0):

its not `TO` but instead `AND`

```
select * 
from AttendanceMaster 
where Date between '8/12/2012' AND '8/20/2012'
```

try casting it to date

```
SELECT * 
FROM   AttendanceMaster 
WHERE  CAST([Date] AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST('2012-08-12' AS DATE) AND CAST('2012-08-20' AS DATE)
```

Comment: Thankx for your answer but, I tried your query.. still i got same result

Comment: try to cast also the date, `CAST([Date] AS DATE)` see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008, you only need to do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   AttendanceMaster 
WHERE  CONVERT(DATE, [Date]) BETWEEN CAST('2012-08-12' AS DATE) AND CAST('2012-08-20' AS DATE)
```

**EDIT**: I am making 2 assumptions here.

1) That you have indeed confirmed that you have data in your *AttendanceMaster* table that has [Date] equal to 12th and/or 20th August 2012 - you dont want to look for something that is not even there in the first place ;)

2) That the [Date] column is most probably of DATETIME SQL Server type

Answer (score 0):

If you give  dates `'2012-08-12'` and `'2012-08-20'` then it returns the data between `'2012-08-12 0:00 AM'` and `'2012-08-20 0:00 AM'` So it does not return the valuesfrom the date `'2012-08-12'`. So you need to write the target date as `'2012-08-21'`

If you have the date `'2012-08-20'` in a variable for ex:

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME
SET @FromDate = '2012-08-12'
SET @ToDate = '2012-08-20'

DECLARE @NextDate DATETIME

SET @NextDate=CAST(FLOOR(CAST(dateadd(day,1,@ToDate) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
/*This Returns the Next Day Date.*/

SELECT * 
FROM AttendanceMaster 
WHERE Date between @Date AND @NextDate
```

Or you can write as

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME
SET @FromDate = '2012-08-12'
SET @ToDate = '2012-08-20'

SELECT * 
FROM AttendanceMaster 
WHERE Date between @Date AND CAST(FLOOR(CAST(dateadd(day,1,@ToDate) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: `2012-08-12` is still ambiguous for some regional settings. `20120812` would be safe no matter what language settings are in place. And if you're going to go to the next day, it's usually better to start using inclusive start date and exclusive end date (`Date >= @Date and Date < @NextDate`) rather than `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `<, <=, >=, or >` because they allow more flexibility than BETWEEN and you have the choice to including or exclude the endpoints. 
So you can rewrite your query like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM AttendanceMaster 
WHERE Date > '8/12/2012 00:00:00' AND Date < '8/21/2012 00:00:00'
```

Plz note that in the above query the end date is 21st and not 20th.

Also remember that by default SQL Server will take any date like '8/20/2012' AS '8/20/2012 00:00:00' and therefore any datetime greater than this will not appear in result if you use BETWEEN or if you dont specify the exact time stamp.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Inclusive start (`>=`) and exclusive end (`<`) are generally the preferred forms, and easiest to reason about (your current query is excluding anything that occurs at *exactly* `'2012-08-12T00:00:00'`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That what I said '<,>,<=,>=' give you the flexibility to include/exclude whatever you want specifically. Here too if th OP wishes to include 00:00:00 he would just have to change '>' to '>='. Anyways do you know of any reason why one should prefer 'BETWEEN' over these operators.

Comment: I was just pointing out that the most commonly used form when working with `datetimes` was inclusive, exclusive. And no, I wouldn't prefer `BETWEEN` since it doesn't offer that option.